# Non-VNet Injected Databricks Workspace

Tags: azure, databricks, vnet

If I have a non-vnet injected Databricks workspace setup, how can I update it to be vnet injected without eliminating the workspace and starting over?

Answer (score 0):

According to Databricks documentation:

**"You cannot replace the VNet for an existing workspace."**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/network/classic/vnet-inject

And you can see that the networking settings for the workspace are grayed out.
[image: network settings]

See this article for help with migrating objects between workspaces - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/howto-regional-disaster-recovery#detailed-migration-steps